# Angular2/4 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'three' in '..\app' resolve 'three' in '..\app'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

i'm new on angular and typescript, and i'm struggling for import the @types/three npm package, i just create a fresh angular project and i try to import and use the three package but i keep getting this error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'three' in 'E:\wamp64\www\pro-website-angular5\src\app'
```

i must be doing some newby mistake but i can't figure out, and this is my code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
  title = new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1);

}
```

Comment: is the path 'three' correct as a relevant path to this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly install the required packages.

```
yarn add three @types/three
```

Then just import `Vector3` from `"three"`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Vector3 } from "three";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
  title = new Vector3(1,1,1);

}
```

Comment: thank you, that worked. i install yarn and just run this comand line, wierd beacuse i alredy had installed with npm.